# Bad Request: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'clear'

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I installed cassandra and run cqlsh:

```
Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.10 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
Use HELP for help.
```

and enter clear command on cqlsh. But i got this

```
cqlsh> clear;
Bad Request: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'clear'
cqlsh> clear
   ... ;
Bad Request: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'clear'
cqlsh>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the clear command was added in Cassandra 2.2.1 ([commit](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/commit/b204803274126602952cb167a6c33864922836eb)) and you're using very old 2.0.10. If you just learning Cassandra, start with Cassandra 4.x, not use the version that was released 8 years ago...

Comment: Thanks, is there a  download link to it on the Windows?

Comment: Cassandra 4.0 removed native support for Windows - use Docker instead to run on Windows. Or use latest 3.x version